# Change text color of \insertsection in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using the code below to start each section in my slides but the text color of the section is black even though I specified white, how can I force it to be white?

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=white, bg=cbg}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{centering}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{centering}
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=black, bg=mbg}
}
```

Comment: and `cgb` and `mbg` what colors are?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina cgb is orange like and mbg is grey like

Comment: Activate the desired color using, for example, `\usebeamerfont{section title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{background canvas}\insertsection\par`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have your actual colors, I just chose random ones. Before `\insertsection`, you can just add `\color{<your color>}` as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern,xcolor}

\AtBeginSection{%
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=white, bg=blue!10}%cbg
\begin{frame}
    \begin{centering}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\color{blue!70!green}\insertsection\par
    \end{centering}
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=black, bg=red!10}%mbg
}

\title{Test Document}
\author{My Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\titlepage

\section{Test Section}

\begin{frame}{Test}
    Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]